# issues with wordpress redirection to https instead of http site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

All,

I had some mod rewrite rules for wordpress which were working fine until i tested today.All my requests are going through https despite of clear redirection in my mod rewrite to http link.

Following is the redirect i have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mycompany\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abc/?$ http://ww2.mycompany.com/test/abc.html/? [R=301,L]
```

If i go ahead and type www.mycompany.com/abc in url it redirects me to https://ww2.mycompany.com/test/abc.html/ instead of http://ww2.mycompany.com/test/abc.html/

Not sure what changed as it was working when i implemented atleast a year ago.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you look on the net panel of your browser development tool and comment on all the redirections that actually are shown?

Comment: Dumb question: If you go into Wordpress -> Settings, what is the site url saved as in the Wordpress database?

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mycompany\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ http://ww2.mycompany.com/test/abc.html/? [R=301,L]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.